# Split comma-separated strings into boolean columns

Tags: r

I have:

```
id choice
----------
1  "a,b,c"
2  "c"
3  "a,c"
4  "b,c"
```

I need

```
id a b c
---------
1  1 1 1
2  0 0 1
3  0 0 1
4  0 1 1
```

(or equivalent with TRUE/FALSE values)

Is there any way to do this in R? I've looked into `strsplit` but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package is designed to do.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(DF, "choice", sep = ",", mode = "binary", 
         type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
#   id choice_a choice_b choice_c
# 1  1        1        1        1
# 2  2        0        0        1
# 3  3        1        0        1
# 4  4        0        1        1
```

---

This uses `DF` from @G.Grothendieck's answer as the input:

```
Lines <- 'id choice
----------
1  "a,b,c"
2  "c"
3  "a,c"
4  "b,c"'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, comment = "-", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! splitstackshape is awesome.

Comment: `cSpit` is a really nice family of functions that is great for tidying pesky data types.  Nice work +1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
txt = 'id choice
----------
1  "a,b,c"
2  "c"
3  "a,c"
4  "b,c"'

library(dplyr)

txt %>% textConnection %>% 
  read.table(skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  select(V2) %>% unlist %>%
  strsplit("[,]") %>%
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(t(table(c(x, "a", "b", "c"))>1))) %>%
  rbind_all
```

then you'll get

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

      a     b    c
1  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
2 FALSE FALSE TRUE
3  TRUE FALSE TRUE
4 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strsplit` to split `choice` creating `s` and give it `DF$id` as names.  From `s` extract a vector of all the levels, `all_lev`.  Then `sapply` a function over `s` which creates a factor from each component of `s` and runs `table` on it.  Finally transpose that.

```
s <- setNames( strsplit(DF$choice, ","), DF$id )
all_lev <- sort(unique(unlist(s)))
m <- t(sapply(s, function(x) table(factor(x, lev = all_lev))))
```

This gives the following matrix where the row names are the id's:

```
> m
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 0 0 1
3 1 0 1
4 0 1 1
```

If you prefer a data frame then using `m` above:

```
data.frame(id = rownames(m), m)
```

**Note 1:** If we knew that the levels were always `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` then we could hard code `all_lev`shortening it to:

```
s <- setNames( strsplit(DF$choice, ","), DF$id )
m <- t(sapply(s, function(x) table(factor(x, lev = c("a", "b", "c")))))
```

**Note 2:** We assumed that `DF` was this:

```
Lines <- 'id choice
----------
1  "a,b,c"
2  "c"
3  "a,c"
4  "b,c"'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, comment = "-", as.is = TRUE)
```

**Update** Shortened answer.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes like @kohske did that your data actually looks like you provided.  If it does not please use `dput` in the future to share data:

```
txt = 'id choice
----------
1  "a,b,c"
2  "c"
3  "a,c"
4  "b,c"'

dat <- setNames(read.table(text=txt, skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
    strsplit(strsplit(txt, "\n")[[1]][1], "\\s+")[[1]]
)

library(qdapTools)

matrix2df(mtabulate(unlist(lapply(split(dat[[2]], dat[[1]]), 
    strsplit, ",\\s*"), recursive=FALSE)), "id")
```

I hate nested calls since I became familiar with `magrittr`'s pipe `%>%` so here it is using the pipe:

```
library(magrittr)

txt %>% read.table(text=., skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    setNames(strsplit(strsplit(txt, "\n")[[1]][1], "\\s+")[[1]]) %>%
    with(split(choice, id)) %>%
    lapply(strsplit, ",\\s*") %>%
    unlist(recursive=FALSE) %>%
    mtabulate %>%
    matrix2df("id")

##   id a b c
## 1  1 1 1 1
## 2  2 0 0 1
## 3  3 1 0 1
## 4  4 0 1 1
```