# cSplit_e not returning a binary data frame

Tags: r, splitstackshape, csplit

I have a data frame with a `Genre` column that has rows like `Action,Romance`. I want to split those values and create a binary vector. If `Action,Romance,Drama` are all the possible genres, then the above mentioned row would be `1,1,0` in the output data frame.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387859/dummify-character-column-and-find-unique-values/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557885/split-comma-separated-strings-into-boolean-columns) SO posts, and [this CRAN doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/splitstackshape.pdf) covering cSplit_e, but when I use it I'm not getting a binary dataframe output, I'm getting the original data frame with a few values scrambled.

```
a = cSplit_e(df4, "Genre", sep = ",", mode = "binary", type = "character", drop=TRUE, fixed=TRUE,fill = 0)
```

Edit: The issue appears to be that it's adding the new columns to the old data frame, instead of creating a new frame. How can I get the Genres into their own frame?

```
> names(a)
 [1] "Title"             "Year"              "Rated"             "Released"          "Runtime"           "Genre"             "Director"          "Writer"            "Actors"           
[10] "Plot"              "Language"          "Country"           "Awards"            "Poster"            "Metascore"         "imdbRating"        "imdbVotes"         "imdbID"           
[19] "Type"              "tomatoMeter"       "tomatoImage"       "tomatoRating"      "tomatoReviews"     "tomatoFresh"       "tomatoRotten"      "tomatoConsensus"   "tomatoUserMeter"  
[28] "tomatoUserRating"  "tomatoUserReviews" "tomatoURL"         "DVD"               "BoxOffice"         "Production"        "Website"           "Response"          "Budget"           
[37] "Domestic_Gross"    "Gross"             "Date"              "Genre_Action"      "Genre_Adult"       "Genre_Adventure"   "Genre_Animation"   "Genre_Biography"   "Genre_Comedy"     
[46] "Genre_Crime"       "Genre_Documentary" "Genre_Drama"       "Genre_Family"      "Genre_Fantasy"     "Genre_Film-Noir"   "Genre_Game-Show"   "Genre_History"     "Genre_Horror"     
[55] "Genre_Music"       "Genre_Musical"     "Genre_Mystery"     "Genre_N/A"         "Genre_News"        "Genre_Reality-TV"  "Genre_Romance"     "Genre_Sci-Fi"      "Genre_Short"      
[64] "Genre_Sport"       "Genre_Talk-Show"   "Genre_Thriller"    "Genre_War"         "Genre_Western"
```

Comment: You'll have to show a few sample rows where that doesn't work. This works, for example: `df4 <- data.frame(Genre = c("Action,Romance", "Action,Romance,Drama"));cSplit_e(df4, "Genre", ",", mode = "binary", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)`.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that snippet! It made me double check the returned frame, and I found that the binary data is being added but its modifying the old frame instead of returning a new one. Is returning a new one possible? Should I just create a separate frame from the original `Genre` data and then use `cSplit_e` to modify it, separate of the rest of the data?

Comment: Lots of info in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387859/dummify-character-column-and-find-unique-values)

Comment: @JamesL., are you just asking how to get just the "Genre" columns without all the other columns? Maybe: `a[startsWith(names(a), "Genre")]`?

Comment: Wow that's great, thank you! Write it up into an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drop` argument only applies to the column being split, not all of the other columns in the `data.frame`. Thus, to subsequently extract just the split columns, use the original column name and extract just those columns.

Example:

```
> a <- cSplit_e(df4, "Genre", ",", mode = "binary", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
> a
  id Genre_Action Genre_Drama Genre_Romance
1  1            1           0             1
2  2            1           1             1
> a[startsWith(names(a), "Genre")]
  Genre_Action Genre_Drama Genre_Romance
1            1           0             1
2            1           1             1
```

Where:

```
df4 <- structure(list(Genre = c("Action,Romance", "Action,Romance,Drama"), id = 1:2), 
  .Names = c("Genre", "id"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```